# Unable to add action listener in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, listener

I keep getting error that I cannot add action listener to object. I am trying to add it to my main frame in order to set it in the correct location.

```
public class Grid extends JPanel{
    public Grid (String title){
       setLayout(null);
       setSize(295,295);
       setLocation(10,10);
       buttons = new JButton[5][5];
       for(int row=0; row<5; row++) {
          for(int col=0; col<5; col++) {
              buttons[row][col] = new JButton();
              buttons[row][col].setLocation(5+col*55, 5+row*55);
              buttons[row][col].setSize(50,50);
              buttons[row][col].setBackground(colours[randCol()]);
              buttons[row][col].addActionListener(this);
              add(buttons[row][col]);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: i have implented the actionlistener in the grid class and i receive this,     cgame.Grid is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

Comment: [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 4):

> i have implented the actionlistener in the grid class and i receive this, cgame.Grid is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

That is because whenever a class implements an interface, it needs to ***override*** all available abstract methods from the interface (be it you are interested to use it or not).

Under the interface of `ActionListener`, there is one abstract method

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
```

If your **Grid** class implements **ActionListener**, then it shall override it as well:

```
class Grid extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    //your other attributes, initializations & constructors..

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //your actions..
    }
}
```

---

*I would advise you to use a Layout for your Grid class. From the naming of your class `Grid`. You can consider using **GridLayout** if you intend to arrange your components into boxes (or grids) of similar sizes. Alternatively, you may consider **GridBagLayout** if some of your grids has different width and/or height.*

Comment: int nummoves = 0;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    for(int row=0; row<5; row++) {
      for(int col=0; col<5; col++) {
        if (a.getSource() == buttons[row][col]) {
          column.setText("COL: " + (col+1));
          rows.setText("ROW: " + (row+1));
          nummoves++;
          moves.setText("Moves: " + nummoves);
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: @SamKadish What do you mean by those codes? You can always add additional codes into your current question by clicking `edit`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `ActionListener` class in Grid class. Only then you can pass **this** to the `addActionListener()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement ActionListener class

```
public class Grid extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JButton[][] buttons;
    public Grid (String title){
       setLayout(null);
       setSize(295,295);
       setLocation(10,10);
       buttons = new JButton[5][5];
       for(int row=0; row<5; row++) {
          for(int col=0; col<5; col++) {
              buttons[row][col] = new JButton();
              buttons[row][col].setLocation(5+col*55, 5+row*55);
              buttons[row][col].setSize(50,50);
              buttons[row][col].addActionListener(this);
              add(buttons[row][col]);
          }
       }
   }    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

`ActionListener` is an interface and therefore you have to override all the methods. I thought that was obvious, that is why I did not explicitly point that out. Sorry for that, but you have to know that. If you have `implements`, then it is always an interface and you have to implement all the methods it contains. This is one of the basic rules in Java.